# django: left outer join (how to preselect a related object from "many" side)

Tags: django, left-join

Basically I have models Image and Member and I want to preselect for each user his profile image if it exists. In pure sql, I would do this with left outer join. How to do that with django ORM?

```
class Media(models.Model, WebModel):
    title = models.CharField('title', max_length=128, default='', db_index=True, blank=True)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, null=True, default=None, related_name='member_%(class)s_set')
    profile = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True



class Image(Media):
    image = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='uploads',
                                processors=[ResizeToFit(width=1024, height=1024, upscale=False)],
                                format='JPEG',
                                options={'quality': 75})



class Member(models.Model, WebModel):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=64, default='')
    phone = models.CharField('phone', max_length=32, default='', blank=True)
    sex = models.IntegerField('sex', null=True, default=None, choices=sexes)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [`QuerySet.prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

Unfortunately, `prefetch_related` doesn't support filtering (yet), and `filter`-ing on the `Member.media_set` QuerySet will create a new database query.

You have two options here:

- Do the filtering in Python to find `Media` with `profile == True`
- Wait for Django 1.7 and use the new [`Prefetch` lookup object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/queries/#django.db.models.Prefetch).

---

If you were to do the filtering in Python, you would do something like:

```
profile_pictures = [media for media in member.media_set.all() if media.profile]
```

This will be faster than querying the database if you don't have too many images. You'll want to benchmark.

Comment: can you show the query and how to access the profile image afterwards?

Comment: ye, with that code I would also need associate each profile image with its user so that is not gonna be a way. I though you will use the prefetch_related thing: `user_images=User.objects.prefetch_related('member_image_set').member_image_set` and `profile_image=filter(lambda i: i.profile, user_images)` but that would be also slow. With `Prefetch('member_image_set', queryset=Image.objects.filter(profile=True))` this is gonna be much faster cause user_images will contain at most one image (no need to filter).